# Use Pandas string method 'contains' on a Series containing lists of strings

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas

Given a simple Pandas Series that contains some strings which can consist of more than one sentence:

```
In:
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series(['This is a long text. It has multiple sentences.','Do you see? More than one sentence!','This one has only one sentence though.'])

Out:
0    This is a long text. It has multiple sentences.
1                Do you see? More than one sentence!
2             This one has only one sentence though.
dtype: object
```

I use pandas string method `split` and a regex-pattern to split each row into its single sentences (which produces unnecessary empty list elements - any suggestions on how to improve the regex?).

```
In:
s = s.str.split(r'([A-Z][^\.!?]*[\.!?])')

Out:
0    [, This is a long text.,  , It has multiple se...
1        [, Do you see?,  , More than one sentence!, ]
2         [, This one has only one sentence though., ]
dtype: object
```

This converts each row into lists of strings, each element holding one sentence.

Now, my goal is to use the string method `contains` to check each element in each row seperately to match a specific regex pattern and create a new Series accordingly which stores the returned boolean values, each signalizing if the regex matched on at least one of the list elements.

I would expect something like:

```
In:
s.str.contains('you')

Out:
0   False
1   True
2   False
```

<-- Row 0 does not contain `'you'` in any of its elements, but row 1 does, while row 2 does not.

However, when doing the above, the return is

```
0   NaN
1   NaN
2   NaN
dtype: float64
```

I also tried a list comprehension which does not work:

```
result = [[x.str.contains('you') for x in y] for y in s]
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'
```

Any suggestions on how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use python [`find()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.find) method

```
>>> s.apply(lambda x : any((i for i in x if i.find('you') >= 0)))
0    False
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool
```

I guess `s.str.contains('you')` is not working because elements of your series is not strings, but lists. But you can also do something like this:

```
>>> s.apply(lambda x: any(pd.Series(x).str.contains('you')))
0    False
1     True
2    False
```

Comment: Hooray, thanks! I prefer the latter one in my case though because `contains` lets you search with a regex while `find` expects a string. However, in simple cases, when no regex is needed, find will probably be faster I guess.

Comment: @Dirk, just in case - you can use `re` module to find by regexp - https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#module-re