# pandas df subset by string in column with lists

Tags: python, string, list, pandas, series

I have a complex, large pandas dataframe with one column, X that can contain either one list or a list of lists. I'm curious if the solution can apply to any content though, so I give a mock example with one element of X being a string as well:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1, 1, 3], 
    'B': ['a', 'e', 'f'], 
    'X': ['something', ['hello'], [['something'],['hello']]]}
)
```

I want to get the subset of that dataframe, df2, for which column X contains the substring "hello", when whatever is in there is read as a string.

```
>>> df2
   A  B                       X
0  1  e                 [hello]
1  3  f  [[something], [hello]]
```

I have tried extensive combinations of str() and .str.contains, apply, map, .find(), list comprehensions, and nothing seems to work without getting into loops (related questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44126089/pandas-isin-for-list-of-values-in-each-row-of-a-column/44126264#44126264) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27300070/use-pandas-string-method-contains-on-a-series-containing-lists-of-strings). What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding `astype` before `str.contains`

```
df1[df1.X.astype(str).str.contains('hello')]
Out[538]: 
   A  B                       X
1  1  e                 [hello]
2  3  f  [[something], [hello]]
```

Comment: @JRCX yw~ :-) happy coding

Answer (score 5):

You can use np.ravel() to flatten nested list and use in operator

```
df1[df1['X'].apply(lambda x: 'hello' in np.ravel(x))]

    A   B   X
1   1   e   [hello]
2   3   f   [[something], [hello]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Borrowing from @wim https://stackoverflow.com/a/49247980/2336654

The most general solution would be to allow for arbitrarily nested lists.  Also, We can focus on the string elements being equal rather than containing.

```
# This import is for Python 3
# for Python 2 use `from collections import Iterable`
from collections.abc import Iterable

def flatten(collection):
    for x in collection:
        if isinstance(x, Iterable) and not isinstance(x, str):
            yield from flatten(x)
        else:
            yield x

df1[df1.X.map(lambda x: any('hello' == s for s in flatten(x)))]

   A  B                       X
1  1  e                 [hello]
2  3  f  [[something], [hello]]
```

So now if we complicate it

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1, 1, 3, 7, 7], 
    'B': ['a', 'e', 'f', 's', 's'], 
    'X': [
        'something',
        ['hello'],
        [['something'],['hello']],
        ['hello world'],
        [[[[[['hello']]]]]]
    ]}
)

df1

   A  B                       X
0  1  a               something
1  1  e                 [hello]
2  3  f  [[something], [hello]]
3  7  s           [hello world]
4  7  s     [[[[[['hello']]]]]]
```

Our filter does not grab `hello world` and does grab the very nested `hello`

```
df1[df1.X.map(lambda x: any('hello' == s for s in flatten(x)))]

   A  B                       X
1  1  e                 [hello]
2  3  f  [[something], [hello]]
4  7  s     [[[[[['hello']]]]]]
```